# How many temporary objects are created when I return a string from an inline function?

Tags: c++, string, inline-code

Consider the following code:

```
QSqlQuery *queryQt; // represents a row in a database table

inline std::string getCString(size_t col) {
     return queryQt->value(col).toString().toStdString();
}
```

where `queryQt->value(col).toString()` represents a string value of a specific column of the row in the database.

Let us assume that the compiler has all the optimizations on.

Question: is the following code:

```
std::string a = T.getCString(0);
```

equivelent to

```
std::string a = queryQt->value(col).toString().toStdString();
```

or to

```
std::string temp = queryQt->value(col).toString().toStdString();
std::string a = temp;
```

?

Question Update:

does it make a difference, if I add const to the return type?

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly?

Comment: @constantin not really. This is simplified version of the code, where I return const data, etc.. But thanks for the hint..

Comment: Due to allowed copy elision, this can be different. But you can always try it out in your compiler (and flags) by making your ctors (and dtors) verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the following code is *initializing* `a` and not assigning to it

```
std::string a = T.getCString(0);
```

is equivalent to

```
std::string a(T.getCString(0)); // Construct "a" with return value of function.
```

or

```
std::string a(std::string(queryQt->value(0).toString().toStdString()));
```

This means there will be a copy construction of `std::string` when returning from the function and another copy construction when constructing `a` from the return value. So 2 copies.

However on C++11 compilers, *move construction* will be used instead when constructing the return value and `a` as both `std::string` objects constructed from is temporaries. This means that there will be only 2 moves instead of 2 copies.

And finally because of [*copy elision optimizations*](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) the compiler will most likely elide the copies all together and simply construct the `std::string` directly in `a`, resulting in no copies at all.

Inlining the function have no relevance on the number of copies being made. Changing the return type to `const` will prevent move construction as you cant move from a const object.

[**Look at this live example using my noisy class**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec550fb13f5ef5b4)

Comment: Changing the return type to `const` means that in C++11 it's copied from, not moved from (you can't move from a `const` object, even a temporary). So in principle it could affect the number of copies, but provided the copy/move is elided, it wouldn't affect the number.

Comment: @Snps wow. what a surprising effect to have a const! Very nice and intuitive explanation

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to

```
std::string temp = queryQt->value(col).toString().toStdString();
std::string a = temp;
```

In theory, at least. Depending on your actual compiler and its settings, the function might not get inlined, even with the `inline` keyword. Most modern compilers (on release settings) will also optimize the code to be

```
std::string a = queryQt->value(col).toString().toStdString();
```